# Использование WebSocket JS в Приложение магазина Windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, windows-8, winrt

Есть скрипт на php, работающий с WebSocket, писал сам т.к. на момент написания не было готовых решений.

Инициализация:

```
$host = '192.168.10.225'; //host
$port = '3994'; //port
//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
//bind socket to specified host
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);
//listen to port
socket_listen($socket);
```

И код клиента(Своя обертка над WebSocket):

```
Socket.bind('open', function () {
            Socket.send({ name: 'alex', status: 'online' });
        });
        Socket.init("ws://192.168.10.225:3994/shell/rest.sock.php");
...
var Socket = (function(){
    var socket;
    var self = {
        init: function(host){
            socket = new WebSocket(host);    
            socket.onopen    = function(e){ callEventList('open', e) };
            socket.onmessage = function(e){ callEventList('message', e) };
            socket.onclose   = function(e){ callEventList('close', e) };
        },
        send: function (msg) {
...
```

Работает везде: chrome/firefox/opera/ie/android/ios

Но при попытке соединиться в Windows store app js, выдает ошибку:

> SCRIPT12029: WebSocket Error: Network
>   Error 12029, Не удается установить
>   связь с сервером

Что довольно странно т.к. тот же код работает в ie.

Подскажите, где может быть ошибка и куда копать?